# How do I create pull quotes in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Can I install an app to make [pull quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote) in Google Drive? Or can I somehow create them using clever tricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done some research and came to the conclusion that it can't be done in Google Docs. This thread in the [Google Product Forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/EYY5eJBX9JU) shows all kinds of negative energy around this topic.

One user suggested taking a screenshot of a Google Spreadsheet that can be imported into the Google Doc: [Jack Kleeman](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/EYY5eJBX9JU/2A7Tz0hFViQJ)

**UPDATE**

Here's my own attempt: [image: pull quotes]

I've included the Google-Documents file, with table color set black: [Pull Quotes](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/document/d/1Jtu54t6CyGv65iFRoVyv4H8GV4NcWl03vcqAIrnollI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the insights! As a former engineer for Google Docs, I was already depressed over having to ask this question ... and that list thread made me, well, more depressed. Nice workaround! :D

Answer (score 2):

There is a very very limited work around for this.

You set your quote in a table in your document by inserting a 1x1 table where you want the quote to go. Set the background of the table and the background of the text to the same color, and adjust the table's column width if necessary.

This screenshot shows what I was going for. It doesn't allow you to align the table to fit inside of another column of text, but it is at least a good way to insert a quote and set it apart from the formatting of the rest of the document.

[image]